# Replacement/substitute for a GRX 600/800 crankset

Tags: crankset, grx

I'm currently building a gravel bike from (almost) scratch.
Due to the lack of availability of the GRX crankset in Europe, I'm looking for a replacement part of the 2x11 GRX 600/800 crankset.

So my questions are:

1. Any reference I can use instead of the GRX crankset?
2. On the Internet there are a lot of GRX810 crankset available. Is the left arm is provided? (e.g: https://www.bike-discount.de/fr/shimano-grx-fc-rx810-2-2x11-vitesses-manivelle-48/31)
3. I see everywhere people speaking about a clearance of 2.5mm. Is it on the crankset or on the derailleur? Is there any picture that can help comparing a GRX groupset with a classical one?

Note: this is my future build:

- 2x11 105 R7000 lever/shifters
- Juin Tech hybrid brake calipers
- GRX rx810 rear derailleur
- GRX rx810 front derailleur
- KMX 11 chain
- crankset ???
- DT swiss C 1800 wheels

Thanks!

Comment: welcome. I altered the title slightly, as I think this will be a bit clearer to English speakers.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Please note that I had to correct something after you accepted it: don't use SRAM 12s cranks with a Shimano drivetrain. I had forgot about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the reference to 2.5mm that you heard means that the [chainline](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html) on GRX is 2.5mm further out than Shimano’s road chainline. This can be seen on Shimano’s site. The [GRX chainline](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-di2/FC-RX810-2.html) is 47.0mm, measured from the centerline of the bike to the center of the two chainrings. The chainline for Shimano’s current [road groups](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/ultegra-r8000/FC-R8000.html) is 43.5mm.

(As a side note, the 47.0mm GRX chainline minus the 43.5mm road chainline is a 3.5mm difference. The interviews and reviews all did say the chainline was moved by 2.5mm. I don’t know why there is this discrepancy.)

You may be able to get away with using a standard Shimano road crank, although the shifting might be impaired and you probably won’t have the gear you want (you’d be limited to a 50/34 gear). For a different replacement crankset, you’d want to find a crank with a chainline of 45.0 to 47.0mm - or in theory something a bit wider than 47.0 might be fine also, but I don’t think any road or gravel cranks with wider chain lines exist.

Full Speed Ahead has [one option](https://shop.fullspeedahead.com/en/prodotti_1/cranksets/gossamer-pro-modular-agx) that's relatively inexpensive that has a 46mm chainline. This isn't an exhaustive list of potentially compatible cranks. [White Industries’ R30 crankset](https://www.whiteind.com/product/r30-cranks/) lists a 2x chainline of 45mm and says that Shimano derailleurs, including GRX, work best with it. However, this is a niche US manufacturer and it may be hard to get in Europe. However, this is why I think a 45.0mm chainline should work OK with GRX. Rotor is a Spanish company that makes modular cranksets, and they have [an option](https://rotorbike.com/catalog/default/rotor/road/cranks/aldhu-spider-mount-crankset-kit-24-mm.html) for a 46mm chainline - note that they are quite pricey because they're a small operation.

(Sram’s current Force and [Rival Wide](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/pm-riv-w-d1) cranks have 47.5mm chainline. Their [road cranks](https://support.sram.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017318513-What-is-the-chain-line-of-the-new-SRAM-RED-and-Force-eTap-AXS-crankset-chainrings-Is-it-different-than-11-speed-SRAM-road-cranksets-) have 45.0mm chainlines. Those chainlines would work, but do note that their 12s AXS groupsets use a different roller diameter, and thus they won't work well for Shimano chains. The previous version of the answer neglected to mention this because I forgot.)

Cranks are very seldom sold as right arm only or left arm only. They are sold as a pair of arms. In English, the word ”crankset” always means both arms. [Here](https://www.tradeinn.com/bikeinn/en/shimano-grx-rx600-left-crank/137973914/p) is one English advertisement for a GRX left arm only.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very, complete answer!
Any thought on this alternative? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq2uY2WOjjM
Alternative crankset you gave are unfortunately not available in Europe or too expensive...